# How to animate react-native-svg Polygon element?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-svg

Is there a simple way to animate the Polygon element from the react-native-svg library?
I need to animate his shape by animating the points.
I found few examples on how to animate Path element or Circle, but couldn't find anything regarding the Polygon. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bit late to the party, but I've found a solution if you're still interested. It's not exactly 'simple', but it works. There's a library called React Native Reanimated, and it extends the functionality of Animated components
substantially. Here's what I was able to achieve:

[image]

The reason animating Polygons isn't available out of the box is because the standard Animated API only handles simple values, namely individual numbers. The Polygon component in react-native-svg takes props of points, which is an array of each of the points, themselves array of x and y. For example:

```
<Polygon
        strokeWidth={1}
        stroke={strokeColour}
        fill={fillColour}
        fillOpacity={1}
        points={[[firstPointX, firstPointY],[secondPointX, secondPointY]}
 />
```

React Native Reanimated allows you to animate even complex data types. In this case, there is useSharedValue, which functions almost identical to new Animated.value(), and a function called useAnimatedProps, where you can create your points (or whatever else you want to animate) and pass them to the component.

```
     // import from the library 
import Animated, {
      useSharedValue,
      useAnimatedProps,
    } from 'react-native-reanimated';

 // creates the animated component 
 const AnimatedPolygon = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Polygon);

const animatedPointsValues = [
  {x: useSharedValue(firstXValue), y: useSharedValue(firstYValue)},
  {x: useSharedValue(secondXValue), y: useSharedValue(secondYValue)},
];

const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps(() => ({
      points: data.map((_, i) => {
        return [
          animatedPointValues[i].x.value,
          animatedPointValues[i].y.value,
        ];
      }),
    })),
```

Then in your  render/return:

```
  <AnimatedPolygon
  strokeWidth={1}
        stroke={strokeColour}
        fill={fillColour}
        fillOpacity={1}
        animatedProps={animatedProps}
      />
```

Then whenever you update one of those shared values, the component will animate.

I'd recommend reading their docs and becoming familiar with the library, as it will open up a whole world of possibilities:

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/

Also, the animations are handled in the native UI thread, and easily hit 60fps, yet you can write them in JS.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you. To those of you looking at this solution, remember to add "import Animated from react-native-reanimated" and remove the" import Animated from react-native"!!

Comment: also, it looks like react-native-gesture-handler doesn't work well with react-native-svg. I reverted to use PanResponder for drag-n-dropping stuff with react-native-svg, and everything works

Answer (score 0):

react-native-reanimated also supports flat arrays for the Polygon points prop, so we can simplify the animation setup even more.

Full example which will animate the react-native-svg's Polygon when the points prop changes looks like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import Animated, { useAnimatedProps, useSharedValue, withTiming } from 'react-native-reanimated'
import { Polygon } from 'react-native-svg'

interface Props {
    points: number[]
}

const AnimatedPolygonInternal = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Polygon)

export const AnimatedPolygon: React.FC<Props> = ({ points }: Props) => {
    const sharedPoints = useSharedValue(points)

    useEffect(() => {
        sharedPoints.value = withTiming(points)
    }, [points, sharedPoints])

    const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps(() => ({
        points: sharedPoints.value,
    }))

    return <AnimatedPolygonInternal fill="lime" animatedProps={animatedProps} />
}
```